# Reference to the enum from model in Index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I have a trouble with reference to my enum from model in Index view.
Here is my model's code:

```
public enum UnitOfMeasure {
    Item,
    Kilogram,
    Liter, }

public class Product {
    public Product() {
        ProductOccurences = new List<ProductOccurence>(); }

    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPhotoId { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure? UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductPhoto Photo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductOccurence> ProductOccurences { get; set; } }
```

In Index view I have search fields for filtering specific results. You can also search for UnitOfMeasure value (I use @Html.EnumDropDownListFor) - but I can't refer directly to the enum field from my model - because my view is strongly typed:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Product>
```

To show this field with the values of the selection I use the trick:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().UnitOfMeasure, "Select unit of measure")
```

but it's terrible and ugly solution - also with unwanted value loaded by default.
What is the most elegant way to solve this issue in my situation?

Comment: It should not be more different than the way you access `ProductDescription` for instance. The snippet you've shown should be inside something like `@foreach (var item in Model) {`, so you simply ignore the `model` argument and use `item`, e.g. `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => item.UnitOfMeasure, "Select unit of measure")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EnumHelper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitOfMeasure", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(UnitOfMeasure)))
```

OR

You can do like this for strongly typed view:

```
@{ // you can put the following in a back-end method and pass through ViewBag
    var selectList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitOfMeasure))
                         .Cast<UnitOfMeasure>()
                         .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Value = ((int)e).ToString(),
                                 Text = e.ToString()
                             });
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UnitOfMeasure, selectList)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I want.
I chose first option and also I added third argument - with default text.